# mysql checking if user singnig in every second

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, java-8, timeout

i developed application with multiuser account ,,, with javafx - mysql ..
how i make mysql check every second if the users is active or not ,,, so i want prevent user enter to the application from another pc if the application crash accidentally or electric going down ,,, for any reason the user become not active

i made the application signout if the user end the session by closing the application and on exit of the application ,,, but what if this happend accidentally by crashing or electric down or any other reason

Comment: you can use events but every second checking will cost too much performance

Comment: 1. I don't think an event (or MySQL in general) will have anything to do with it. Basically, your app would need to send an "i am still alive" request every second (to your middleware, not mysql). If it doesn't do it, the session will become invalid. 2. Why would you want to even do that? Just make a session invalid if another session is opened (e.g. if you log in somewhere else, you logout in your app - where the logout means: the next request of the app will be denied). That is what probably everyone else does.

Comment: Store a threadsafe `AtomicInteger` that count down from a set number (on a separate thread of course). Every action you perform in the app that sends to the SQL database, reset that counter. If the counter reaches zero, sign out of the app.